# Nginx valid referers add facebook

Tags: php, regex, caching, nginx

I am trying to link my website on my facebook and I am getting a 403. I had my Nginx config blocking all invalid refers and just changed it to add the following. Can someone let me know where I am going wrong I am still getting the 403.

```
  # Caching & Hotlink Protection
  location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    valid_referers none blocked my-site.com *.my-site.com ~.google. ~.yahoo. ~.bing. ~.facebook. ~.fbcdn.;
      if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
      }
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires 30d;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the referer header on the blocked request?

Comment: Facebook only reports and "403" caption in the corner. Can I use curl to test a connection from facebook?

Comment: Just fixed it. When I curled FB I learned it can't redirect to https, needs to be direct. Not 403 returns. Agh.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook needs direct link, can't resolve 403. In post use direct link to https://www.your-site.com